UNISWAP LIQUIDITY NIGHTMARE
I am trying to create uniswap V3 pool. token0 is always 490_000_000 * 1e18 tokens , token1 is changeable , between 1 -100 WETH ( WETH is also 18 decimals)
function createPool(
    address memeTokenAddr
) external payable onlyAllowedContracts returns (address) {
    // Approve the meme token
    IERC20(memeTokenAddr).approve(address(positionManager), TOKEN_FOR_DEX);
    IERC20(address(weth)).approve(address(positionManager), msg.value);

    // Deposit collected ETH as WETH
    weth.deposit{value: msg.value}();

    // Check or create pool
    address pool = uniswapFactory.getPool(
        memeTokenAddr,
        address(weth),
        500
    );
    if (pool == address(0)) {
        pool = uniswapFactory.createPool(memeTokenAddr, address(weth), 500);
    }

    

    // TOKEN_FOR_DEX is always 490_000_000 (18 decimals)
    // msg.value is changeable , around 1 -100 WETH (18 decimals )

    uint256 price = TOKEN_FOR_DEX / msg.value; 

    uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = uint160((sqrt(price) * 2 ** 96));

    // Initialize the pool with the calculated sqrtPriceX96
    IUniswapV3Pool(pool).initialize(sqrtPriceX96);

    INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams
        memory params = INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams({
            token0: memeTokenAddr,
            token1: address(weth),
            fee: 500,
            tickLower: -887220,
            tickUpper: 887220,
            amount0Desired: TOKEN_FOR_DEX,
            amount1Desired: msg.value,
            amount0Min: 0,
            amount1Min: 0,
            recipient: DEAD_ADDRESS, // burn the liquidity
            deadline: block.timestamp + 10 minutes
        });


    // Create pool
    (, , uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1) = positionManager.mint(params);


    return pool;
}

I've tried this code in Base Sepolia network with 2.931 WETH (2.931 * 1e18) but pool took so less token,

amount of WETH doesn’t matter i have tried different amount of WETH, pool takes so less memeToken every time.
So i tried to change places of tokens , i tired to calculate price like this
I've changed places of tokens but here TOKEN_FOR_DEX is so big and price becomes zero and transactions reverts.
So i tried to calculate price like this
uint256 price = msg.value / TOKEN_FOR_DEX;

uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = uint160((sqrt(price) * 2 ** 96));
And the params like this :
    // Initialize the pool with the calculated sqrtPriceX96
    IUniswapV3Pool(pool).initialize(sqrtPriceX96);

    INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams
        memory params = INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams({
            token0: address(weth),
            token1: memeTokenAddr,
            fee: 500,
            tickLower: -887220,
            tickUpper: 887220,
            amount0Desired: msg.value,
            amount1Desired: TOKEN_FOR_DEX,
            amount0Min: 0,
            amount1Min: 0,
            recipient: DEAD_ADDRESS, // burn the liquidity
            deadline: block.timestamp + 10 minutes
        });

but it has reverted again.
pls help

Give all you specific input parameters and the corresponding event log. What is your msg.value ?

changes according to the situation. 2WETH , 3 or 5 WETH, rest of the code reduces 5% of the WETH as a tax, so its around 2.9 WETH , 9.9 WETH .. ofcourse in wei (9900000000000000000)

For the one in the image , what is the msg.value ? @nebula

Can you change the title to something descriptive, please?

Your price computation is wrong, price in a full-range position is expresses as token1/token0, but you have it reverted.
It's best to compute sqrtPriceX96 off-chain anyway, and pass as a parameter to your smart contract, it will be more accurate that way.

I have also tried what you said. the problem is  token1/token0 becomes zero in solidity when token0 is so big , and it reverts by pool. In my case token1 was 3 WETH , token0 was 490M tokens.   My solution was   multiplying price and than dividing back. First i made  " uint256 price = (msg.value * 1e18) / TOKEN_FOR_DEX;" and than "uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = uint160((sqrt(price) * 2 ** 96) / 1e9);", with this problem seems solved but it's not best practice ...
